# How to programmatically replace a string in VBAProject modules?

Tags: excel, vba

I can use GUI Replace (`CTRL+H`) to replace a specific string in all modules in my workbook VBAProject.

Is it available  to do that **programmatically**?

I mean to add a sub on the same workbook to replace all string e.g "`Sheets("Data")."` by "`Sheet01.`"

many thanks for your time of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Changed Toddleson Answer a bit - this should work if you start it in the module

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExampleWithLoop()
    Dim component As Object
    For Each component In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
            Dim module As Object
            Set module = component.CodeModule
             If Not module Is ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBE.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule Then
           If module.CountOfLines > 0 Then
                       Dim moduleText As String
            moduleText = module.Lines(1, module.CountOfLines)
            moduleText = Replace(moduleText, "Sheets(""Data"")", "Sheet01")

            module.DeleteLines 1, module.CountOfLines
            module.AddFromString moduleText
           End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: But it would anyway be better to have the code in a different VBA Project and get the VBA Project from the workbook with the code to change

Comment: Works perfectly as it should

Answer (score 2):

Before you can start working with the code modules programatically, you need to give yourself access to the VBProject for that workbook. In the settings, go to Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings -> Macro Settings -> "Trust access to the VBA project object model" and make sure the check box is checked. Then you can use the `Workbook.VBProject` object.

Then you can do a find and replace like:

```vb
Sub Example()
    Dim module As Object
    Set module = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1").CodeModule
    
    Dim moduleText As String
    moduleText = module.Lines(1, module.CountOfLines)
    moduleText = Replace(moduleText, "Sheets(""Data"")", "Sheet01")
    
    module.DeleteLines 1, module.CountOfLines
    module.AddFromString moduleText
End Sub
```

This would replace every instance of `Sheets("Data")` with `Sheet01` in the module `Module1`

Here's an example that loops through the whole project, but skips the module where the code is currently executing:

```vb
Sub ExampleWithLoop()
    Dim component As Object
    For Each component In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
        If Not component.Name = Me.CodeName Then
            Dim module As Object
            Set module = component.CodeModule
            
            Dim moduleText As String
            moduleText = module.Lines(1, module.CountOfLines)
            moduleText = Replace(moduleText, "Sheets(""Data"")", "Sheet01")
            
            module.DeleteLines 1, module.CountOfLines
            module.AddFromString moduleText
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

If you want to be able to edit the `VBProject` of another workbook,  there are a few steps to complete.

In the Code Window, press <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open the Project Explorer. Find the workbook that has the VBProject you want to edit. Right mouse click the project name (default name is "VBAProject"), and click "VBAProject Properties". In this new window, give your project a unique name.

Then, in the code window, go to Tools -> References and add that workbook as a reference. Click Browse, and add the file manually, since it likely wont be on the list. Once you have done that, you can use the VBAProject name in your code!

For example, I named one of my projects `DS`. Now, in my code I can access its VBProject object with `DS.ThisWorkbook.VBProject`.

Comment: I need to loop all modules ,**regardless it's names**

Comment: You can do `For Each component in ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents` and loop through your VBProject like that. But don't edit the module that is currently executing code, I just crashed my Excel testing that for you, lol.

Comment: I got this error (Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set) @ this line `moduleText = module.Lines(1, module.CountOfLines)` , and surly I commented that line before run  `Set module = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1").CodeModule`

Comment: @Leedo I have added an example with a loop

Comment: `Compile error: Invalid use of Me keyword`

Comment: Try replacing `Me.CodeName` with the name of the module in which the code resides.

Comment: @Domenic ,I tried and got `Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)': Invalid procedure call or argument`

Comment: @Leedo did you put quotation marks around the name? example: `If Not component.Name = "Module1" Then`

Comment: Yes I have put the quotation marks , and the cited `Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)': Invalid procedure call or argument` can not be debugged